# Get the highest point (z) in the image using python

Tags: python, image, numpy, matplotlib

I use this code to get the highest terrain point (z-axis) in the image (Not blurred), is this correct way? and if there is better way than it?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import imread
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import scipy.ndimage as ndimage

imageFile = 'D:\Books\Pav Man\PICS\pic (31)-2.png'
mat = imread(imageFile)
mat = mat[:,:,0] # get the first channel
rows, cols = mat.shape
xv, yv = np.meshgrid(range(cols), range(rows)[::-1])

blurred = ndimage.gaussian_filter(mat, sigma=(5, 5), order=0)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(221)
ax.imshow(mat, cmap='gray')
ax = fig.add_subplot(222, projection='3d')
ax.elev= 75
ax.plot_surface(xv, yv, mat)
ax = fig.add_subplot(223)
ax.imshow(blurred, cmap='gray')
ax = fig.add_subplot(224, projection='3d')
ax.elev= 75
ax.plot_surface(xv, yv, blurred)
# Get highest value #
maxP = 0
for xx in range(0,len(mat)):

    for x in mat[xx]:
        if x>maxP:
            maxP=x
print(maxP)
# -----------------#

plt.show()
```

Comment: Assuming `mat` is as ndarray, you could try [mat.max()](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.max.html)

Comment: thank its work, I note there is no negative value , can I make the mean value (Average) is my zero (reference) to compare it with other values?

Comment: I am not sure I get your question. If you want to create the matrix of the differences between the average and the value you could use `diff = mat - numpy.full_like(mat , mat.mean())`